# Where-Object to match from Left to Right on all prerequires?

Tags: powershell

See the below example code.
I have several objects I need to match on several prerequires.

Lets say I want my Where-Object to not match when the NameRegex is one of the 2 values, the name not equals DisplayName1 and the AccessRights not match.
This means that when I run the below code I want to get Object $User1 back.
This is not happening what so ever.

Should I do this the other way around and then match them in some sort of hashtable?

Has anyone figured this out for a single Where-Object?

```
$User1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Name1'
    DisplayName = 'DisplayName1'
    AccessRights = 'AccessRights1'
}

$User2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Name2'
    DisplayName = 'DisplayName2'
    AccessRights = 'AccessRights2'
}

$User3 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Name3'
    DisplayName = 'DisplayName3'
    AccessRights = 'AccessRights3'
}

$Test = $User1,$User2,$User3

$NameRegex = '^Name2$|^Name3'
$ACRegex = '^AccessRights2$|^AccessRights3$'


$Test | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $NameRegex -and $_.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1' -and $_.AccessRights -notmatch $ACRegex }
```

And some others I've tried:

```
$Test | Where-Object { ($_.Name -notmatch $NameRegex -and $_.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1' -and $_.AccessRights -notmatch $ACRegex) } 
$Test | Where-Object { ((($_.Name -notmatch $NameRegex) -and $_.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1') -and $_.AccessRights -notmatch $ACRegex) } 
$Test | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch ((($_.Name -notmatch $NameRegex) -and $_.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1') -and $_.AccessRights -notmatch $ACRegex) }
```

Comment: `$User1.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1'` returns `$False`. If you "*want to get Object $User1 back.*", the second comparison should be: **`-eq`** (`$True`): `.... -and $_.DisplayName -eq 'DisplayName1' -and ...`

Comment: No, I want it to match on the DisplayName after it matched on the first regex, then DisplayName, and then the last regex.

Comment: The order of the sub-conditions isn't in play for the actual result. Meaning if any of the sub-conditions is `$False` and the logical operators are all **`-and`** the whole condition will never become $True (consequently returns `$False`).

Comment: Your above code doesn't meet your conditions you've asked for. NotMatch on $NameRegex returns $User1. To then notequal  that result on `DisplayName1` will always return nothing as that is the DisplayName on that object. Please clarify what you actually need returned and why.

Comment: I guess you want to do this: `-not ($_.Name -match $NameRegex -and $_.DisplayName -eq 'DisplayName1' -and $_.AccessRights -match $ACRegex)` which is equal to: `$_.Name -notmatch $NameRegex -or $_.DisplayName -ne 'DisplayName1' -or $_.AccessRights -notmatch $ACRegex` (general: `-not ($a -and $b -and $c)` <=> `!$a -or !$b -or !$c`)

Comment: Layered if states is the normal way to implement gradual checks, but avoid that if you can is it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Can't go any other way than if statements I guess